# Регулярные выражения: найти 5 слов и меньше

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!
Нужно найти в тексте выражения с нижними подчеркиваниями, которых не больше 5 во фразе.
Например, в тексте "kjmkjd _lsvsdlk xclc_ sfojlfkl _cslv_ podksckjsfskwofj skfl _lsklsl slcslsla sll dfla ljfk_ sfpowlwfk sladjl _d d d d d d d d_ cjvkdsm _f_" должно найтись:

```
_lsvsdlk xclc\_
_cslv\_
_lsklsl slcslsla sll dfla ljfk\_
_f\_
```

Я пишу регулярное выражение: `_(?:\B\D+?\s?){,5}?\_`
И оно находит все вхождения, что перечислены выше, и `_d d d d d d d d\_` (чего я не хочу искать).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Неясно, что такое "фраза". Почему "slcslsla" должно находить, а "d" или "_d" — нет? Опишите это в вопросе.

Comment: @AлексейР теперь понятней, но почему `\_` в конце вместо оригинального `_`?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то в группах, ограниченных подчеркиванием `_`, должно быть не более 5 слов, т.е. последовательностей символов, разделенных пробелами.
Попробуйте так:

```
_(?:[^_\s]+\s?){0,5}_
```

Если не нужны совпадения с `__` (нулевое кол-во слов внутри подчеркиваний, что формально соответствует задаче), замените `0` в фигурных скобках на `1`.
В выражении:
находим от 0 до 5 групп символов между подчеркиваниями `_`, которые не являются подчеркиваниями и пробелами `[^_\s]+`, но могут быть разделены пробелами `\s?`.
`_d d d d d d d d_` не соответствует, поскольку содержит 8 слов, что больше 5.

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/pdgRsh/1)